# how to set column data type for export xls using alasql?

Tags: angularjs, xlsx, xls, alasql

I want to set the column type when exporting an xls using alasql. I was looking for but I do not understand the documentation. If someone has an example, it would be very helpful. I'm programming in angularjs

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.